# NodeJS how to retry queue job using bull in certain time after that job is failed

Tags: node.js, queue, jobs

I'm trying to create a job that will retry in certain time after that job is failed using `bull queue`. But the job never delayed, always excute right after.
Here my current code :

```
const Queue = require('bull');
const queue = new Queue('send notiffication to main app', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379');
const sendDepositNotificationToMainAppJob = require('../jobs/sendDepositNotificationToMainApp');

 queue.process(new sendDepositNotificationToMainAppJob(depositSuccess));
```

`sendDepositNotificationToMainApp.js`

```
const Queue = require('bull');
const queue = new Queue('send notif to main app', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379');
class sendDepositNotificationToMainApp {
    constructor(depositSuccess){
        return handle(depositSuccess);
    }
}

const handle = async (depositSuccess) => {
  try {
   //some function here
   }.catch(e){
     //if error retry job here 
      queue.add(new sendDepositNotificationToMainApp(depositSuccess), {delay : 5000})
   }

}

module.exports = sendDepositNotificationToMainApp;
```

How do I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 23):

As per the documents [here](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/blob/develop/REFERENCE.md#queueadd)

When you are creating new job You can pass job options. In which there's attempts and backoff option.

In your case while creating job you can just pass

```
Queue.add('<You-job-name>', <Your-Data>, {
   attempts: 5, // If job fails it will retry till 5 times
   backoff: 5000 // static 5 sec delay between retry
});
```

Backoff can be number in ms or you can pass separate backoff option like:

```
interface BackoffOpts{
   type: string; // Backoff type, which can be either `fixed` or `exponential`. 
   //A custom backoff strategy can also be specified in `backoffStrategies` on the queue settings.
   delay: number; // Backoff delay, in milliseconds.
}
```